# Null response from youtube api

Tags: java, youtube, youtube-api

I am getting null response from youtube api and don't have a clue why.

```
    public void test () throws JSONException, IOException, ServiceException
    {
      YouTubeService youtube = new YouTubeService (clientId);
      URL feedUrl = new URL ("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos");
      YouTubeQuery query = new YouTubeQuery(feedUrl);

      query.setFullTextQuery("?category=music");

      VideoFeed videoFeed = youtube.query(query, VideoFeed.class);
      List<VideoEntry> videoEntry = videoFeed.getEntries();

      System.out.println (videoEntry.get(0).getMediaSource());
    }//end
```

This code just prints out null what am I doing wrong

Comment: Debug and watch where is null? Well, clear, that you have null in the mediaSource, that means that the videoEnty you access is not null, but empty.

Comment: That would suggest that all are empty and if so why?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you want to call `setFullTextQuery()` and pass in a random URL query parameter there. I don't know what URL ends up being constructed when you do that, but it's almost certainly not what you want.

Instead, follow the examples at https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_java#Searching_Categories_and_Keywords for setting category filters.